# Imprimir el valor y la posición de una lista

Tags: python, lista

La idea es que el usuario ingrese cualquier tipo de lista y el programa imprima en pantalla cada valor junto a su posición. Ejemplo:

```
lista = ["h","o","l","a"] 

print_valores(lista)
El valor en la posición 0 es h 
El valor en la posición 1 es o
El valor en la posición 2 es l
El valor en la posición 3 es a
```

Comment: Leyendo lo que comentas en las respuestas, puedes usar funciones? o debe ser sin funciones? Porque hay otras alternativas, como `enumerate` para no usar `len`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno haber si te sirve corri e script en python 3:

```
def elementos(lista):
    for i in range(0,len(lista)):
         print(str(i)+'->'+lista[i])
```

Comment: ¿Y existe una manera sin utilizar len?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar:

```
lista = ["h","o","l","a"]
for v in enumerate(lista): 
    print('Valor en posicion {}: {}'.format(*v))
```

Resultando.

```
Valor en posicion 0: h
Valor en posicion 1: o
Valor en posicion 2: l
Valor en posicion 3: a
```

O, de forma más resumida, engorrosa, pero en una línea y más "pythonezco".

```
print('\n'.join(
    map(lambda v: 'valor en posicion {}: {}'.format(*v),enumerate(lista))))
```

Lo que hago es muy sencillo. En ambas "desempaqueto" lo que tenga la tupla que devuelve el iterador `enumerate`.

En el segundo caso prescindí del ciclo `for` utilizando la función `map` para crear objeto map con el contenido `'valor en posicion {}: {}'` cuyos placeholders tendrán lo "desempaquetado" de las tuplas de `enumerate`. Luego, a este objeto map, lo uso como argumento en `join` que juntará cada uno de los valores dentro del `map` con el caracter de salto de línea `'\n'.join(etc...)`

Todavía más "pythonezco" aún, usando python3+ (yo lo probé con 3.6.8)

```
print(
    *map(lambda v: 'valor en posicion %s: %s' % v,
        enumerate(lista)), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Me gusta @Marco como el operador (`*`) puede desempacar argumentos de una **lista** o una **tupla** [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: La version más *pythonic* de hacerlo es con enumerate, los demas ejemplos lo hacen más ofuscados. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera más sencillo :)

```
lista = ["h","o","l","a"] 
index = -1;
for valor in lista:
  index+=1
  print("El valor en la posición " + str(i) + " es: " + valor)
```